# Is there an analogue/primitive of PCA which can be in a metric space rather than a vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, metric-spaces

Principle component analysis [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is done in a vector space, basically projecting a given vector onto the eigen vectors of the covariance matrix.

I'd like to think of a primitive analogoue of PCA, which is defined for a metric space rather than the vector space. The problem in metric space is we may not add the elements, but I'd like to do something in a metric space which kind of resembles or inspired by the PCA in a vector space.

Comment: It can be also asked as what is the basic analogoue of eigen vectors in a metric space.

Comment: You could "project" everything onto a half-line by taking distances from a chosen, fixed point.  Choose two points and you have a sort of "projection" onto the first quadrant, though distances between points won't be as representative as in PCA.

Comment: @Martian : Given a set of points how do we choose these 2 or any nber of points. In PCA we choose them as Eigen vectors of the covariance matrix.

Comment: You're not going to get a "nice" way to choose them like you do in $\mathbb{R}^n$, because there's no canonical way to represent points in a general metric space.  I would choose points that, say, maximize the variance of the set of distances from them or something, but unless you have more structure to your space that's about the best you can do.

Comment: @MartianInvader Assume they form say 10 clusters, I guess it would be best to choose the 10 centroids of these clusters as our points. We can use some clustering algorithm on this metric space to do so. Is this a good idea?